# SQL Server 2005 SSL version on encrypted connections

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssl, tls

Which version of SSL (or TLS) does SQL Server 2005 SP3 use when Force Encryption is on?  I'm running Windows Server 2003 SP2.

Comment: Doesn't really answer your question but I believe you'll need a certificate for encryption as in the Force Encryption flag alone won't turn it on.

Comment: @jl Actually you don't need a certificate.  If no certificate is found in the SQL config, the service account's user store or in the machine store then SQL will generate its own self-signed certificate (starting with SQL 2005).

Answer (score 1):

It will use what ever settings are specified by the certificate specifications.